# Dynamic render react child component

Tags: reactjs

How can i dynamic render react child component? Now that looks like this and its works.

```js
<CustomFieldArea>
                    {(ExampleCustomFields || []).map((e: {
                        field: string;
                        CustomComponent: 'Text' | 'TextArea'
                    }) => {

                        if (e?.CustomComponent === 'Text') {
                            return (
                                <CustomFieldArea.Text
                                    name={e?.field}
                                />
                            )
                        }

                        if (e?.CustomComponent === 'TextArea') {
                            return (
                                <CustomFieldArea.TextArea
                                    name={e?.field}
                                />
                            )
                        }

                    })}
                </CustomFieldArea>
```

Here is the output I’m looking for:

```js
<CustomFieldArea>
                    {(ExampleCustomFields || []).map((e: {
                        field: string;
                        CustomComponent: 'Text' | 'TextArea'
                    }) => {
                        return (
                                <CustomFieldArea[e?.CustomComponent]
                                    name={e?.field}
                                />
                            )
                    })}
                </CustomFieldArea>
```

But it doesnt work. How can i using `<CustomFieldArea[e?.CustomComponent] label={e?.title}>` like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you want something like render props ?

```
<DataProvider render={data => (
  <h1>Hello, {data.target}</h1>
)}/>



<Mouse children={mouse => (
     <p>Current mouse position: {mouse.x}, {mouse.y}</p>
)}/>
```

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

if render props isn't that you want then Use HOC's

```
const menu = [
  { title: 'Home', icon: 'HomeIcon' },
  { title: 'Notifications', icon: 'BellIcon' },
  { title: 'Profile', icon: 'UserIcon' },
]

const Icon = (props) => {
  const { name } = props

  let icon = null
  if (name === 'HomeIcon') icon = HomeIcon
  if (name === 'BellIcon') icon = BellIcon
  if (name === 'UserIcon') icon = UserIcon

  return React.createElement(icon, { ...props })
}
```

Read more [here](https://flaviocopes.com/react-dynamically-render-component/)

Helpful links

- [First](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json)
- [Second](https://j5bot.medium.com/react-dynamically-rendering-different-components-without-switch-the-capitalized-reference-e668d89e460b)

Comment: im trying automatically render react child component with according to data from database. You showed me a beautiful way. This is my solution:

`
return React.createElement(CustomFieldArea[e?.CustomComponent], {
                            name: e?.field,
                            type: "textarea"
                        })
`